# Specific Query runs fine directly or when any change to it is made but in current state takes longer to run

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2000

*Major Update after a couple days of debugging:*

I run a few queries similar to :

```
SELECT RTRIM(part) as part 
FROM tableP pm 
LEFT join tableS s on pm.id = s.id 
INNER JOIN tableC cm ON cm.id = pm.id 
WHERE name = 'NGW'  AND  status NOT IN ('NL', 'Z') 
GROUP BY RTRIM(part), isnull(s.value,0) 
ORDER BY isnull(s.value,0)
```

It is run in Java like so:

```
    PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT RTRIM(part) as part" +
        "FROM tableP pm " +
        "LEFT JOIN tableS s ON pm.id= s.id " +
        "INNER JOIN tableC cm ON cm.id= pm.id " +
        "WHERE name =? AND  status NOT IN ('NL', 'Z') " + 
        "GROUP BY RTRIM(part), isnull(s.value,0) " +
        "ORDER BY isnull(s.value,0) " );
    select.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
          ... Data is Loaded...
```

The queries have been running fine inside of a Java application.  Suddenly 3 or 4 queries of this form went from taking less then a second to over a minute.

I have copied the exact query from SQL Profiler and when run directly on the database it preforms in less then a second. I started to make changes to the query and found any change to the query would return it to 1 second performance **even adding a single space** between a statement.  But as soon as I returned it to its original exact state it would take 60+ seconds.

**Core Question:**
So, I have a fix, but what could cause a query to run differently even with just a change as small as whitespace?

Comment: Please give is a more exact query, with filters, with parameters. From Java and MSSQL EM.

Comment: @gbn,  Updated question to contain exact query (names changed to protect the innocent) and the Java code that calls it.

Comment: Thanks. This eliminates what I *was* going to answer though... sorry!

Comment: Updated the question now that I have zeroed in on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the execution plan is corrupted? Can you try explicitly clearing the plan cache?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175244(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: That sounds logical, I am reading your link and will try it out.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Specifically I used `sp_recompile` on one table that was in all 3 queries and things run fine now.